# Python interpreter not returning user info correctly in Flask tutorial

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am doing Miguel grinberg's flask tutorial and on step 4 Database. 
http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

In this step, in the playtime section, when I open python interpreter from virtual env and type in the commands for adding a user:

```
>> from app import db,models
>> u= models.User(nickname='john', email='john2@gmail.com')
>> db.session.add(u)
>> db.session.commit()
```

Now to retrieve the user info I did the following:

```
>> users= models.User.query.all()
>> users
```

and instead of returning `[<User u'john'>]` I am getting:

```
[<app.models.User object at 0xb74bd1ac>]
```

which seems like I am returned the memory location of John rather than actual name. So what am I doing wrong? Any suggestion?

My code for models.py:

```
from app import db 

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key= True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64),index= True,unique= True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120),index= True,unique= True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post',backref= 'author', lazy='dynamic')

    def _repr_(self):
        return '<User %r>'% (self.nickname)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def _repr_(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

code for db_create.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                        api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

code for db_migrate.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + ('/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (v+1))
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec(old_model, tmp_module.__dict__)
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
                                          SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                                          tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
v = api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print('New migration saved as ' + migration)
print('Current database version: ' + str(v))
```

Also to clarify, I have followed all the steps till now in all 4 parts of the tutorial. working on it in Ubuntu 16.04 vmware version. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your database is working correctly, and you are getting the correct user when you query it. What's not working is how the user object prints itself to the console.

This is controlled by the `__repr__` method defined in the `User` class. You have a typo there, you use `_repr_` instead of `__repr__` (one underbar instead of two on each side of repr).

Comment: Oops! that was silly. Thanks @Miguel  Great tutorial. Learning heaps.